# Visual Studio 2015 keeps getting standard file association for txt files

Tags: windows-10, text-editors, file-association, visual-studio-2015, textfiles

On my System running Windows 10 Professional, I am using Visual Studio 2015, which is the standard program associated to Text-Files, i.e all files with a suffix .txt, which means all files of this type are automatically opened with Visual Studio.

To use another program as default, I right-click a .txt-file, select "open with" and chose another program and tick the checkbox "always open with...". From that time on, my .txt files are opened by that other program (in this case PSPad), which is the behaviour I expect.

However, after I reboot my system, .txt files will reopen in Visual Studio 2015 again, which is not what I expect. So either Visual Studio 2015 itself, or some other process keeps re-assigning the defaul app settings. How can I permanently set PSPad as the default editor for .txt-files?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will attempt to repair any broken file associations (those not associated with a valid application) at startup.
I suggest the following two manipulations.

- Check if `txt` is included in VS
  *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension*,
  and Remove in that case.
- Go to
  *Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol with a program -> Choose default apps by ﬁle type*,
  scroll down to `.txt` and click, then choose your text editor if it is not already set correctly.

If these two measures are not enough, then your Visual Studio setup has a problem.